# Are there any 4-seater cars that don't have a rear window?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I'm looking for a protected getaway car for my escapes in *Grand Theft Auto Online*. Are there any 4-seater cars that don't have a rear window?

Comment: Are there *any* cars without rear window?

Comment: OP probably meant a 2-door 4-seater.

Comment: The supercars don't have rear windows, but i have encountered no 4 seaters which have no rear windows. haven't tested if a van can have 4 people in it.

Comment: A van can seat 4 - two in the front, two sitting on a bench in the back. Easy to test with the Lost MC vans you have to steal for Trevor, two can shoot out the back during the getaway.

Answer (score 3):

No - if you skim through https://googledrive.com/host/0B-Q7WnzcPvLtLVVoM3otTVlnOFE/all.htm you can see that basically anything with 4 seats is going to have a back window. My best experience with getaway vehicles so far have been the Jackal (inexpensive, easily stolen) or the Exemplar (200k or so, performs well.) Super cars don't appear to have back windows, or they're very small but I've managed to shoot and kill other players in them during a chase.

I'd suggest stealing a jackal and tweaking it out a bit to try, since you can get the car for 'free'.

Just to note, my experience with regular vans and cube vans is that the back doors or cargo door will stay open during travel, especially if people are shooting at pursuers.

Answer (score 2):

Sandking XL and buy the painted double roll bar (chassis).
bullets will no longer enter from the rear window.
shooting out of the back from the truck will break the glass.
however it will still block shots from entering even with the window broken.
works on the current 360 version. don't know about ne... current gen consoles.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for a protected getaway car for my escapes

I'm interpreting the above to mean that you want a car that is armored or bulletproof from the rear, for ease of escapes, and not necessarily one that "doesn't have a rear window."

There are several 4-seater cars with an armored and/or bulletproof rear. The website, [gtabase.net lists 39 of them](https://www.gtabase.com/grand-theft-auto-v/vehicles/#sort=attr.ct533.frontend_value&sortdir=asc&attr.ct30.value=bullet-resistant-rear&attr.ct1.value=commercial%2Ccompacts%2Ccoupes%2Ccycles%2Cindustrial%2Cmilitary%2Cmuscle%2Coff-road%2Copen-wheel%2Crc%2Csedans%2Cservice%2Csports%2Csports-classic%2Csuper%2Csuvs%2Ctuners%2Cutility%2Cvans&attr.ct11.value=4%2C16&page=1) at the time of writing.

I'm listing two of those cars that I think are the most useful for a *GTA Online* player:

- [Karin **Kuruma (Armored)**](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Kuruma_(Armored)) - Has a rear window, but armored and bulletproof (all of its windows are armored and bulletproof). It is relatively cheap compared to other armored and bulletproof cars, which combined with its utility, makes it a recommended purchase for any *GTA Online* player.

- [Pegassi **Toreador**](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Toreador) - Has no rear window, so it's bulletproof from the rear, but not from the sides and front. It is currently the fastest 4-seater car (mainly due to its rocket boost ability), helping with escapes. It can be equipped with homing missiles, allowing you to easily get rid of pursuers, and has a submarine mode, allowing you to travel or escape by water.